# Format an iterator in LabVIEW

Tags: iterator, while-loop, format, labview

I am writing out a series of files in a while loop, they are named

`1.dat, 2.dat, 3.dat...`

but I need the numbers to be formatted to -

```
00001.dat, 00002.dat, 00003.dat...
```

so that the file order is maintained when reading them back in. Is there a way to change the format of the while loop iterator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "format into string" node, it allows to pad integer with zeros:

[image]

Comment: Note that this starts with 000, and has 3 digits.